# Delay for CNAME entries on Cloudflare, or any other restriction?

Tags: cname-record, cloudflare

I have a domain like "**example.org**" at CloudFlare.

I have a CDN at Amazon and would like a CNAME subdomain pointing to the CDN host.

I have added a **CNAME** called "**documents.public**" pointing to the CDN host.

However, it's been about an hour now, but the CNAME doesn't seem to kick in. I've tried using http://mxtoolbox.com to look it up (like **documents.public.example.org**).

Anyone aware of any restrictions on the CNAME at CloudFlare? Does it have to be a simple name, meaning my dot in there (**documents.public** instead of **documentspublic**) is ruining it?

Or do I just need to be more patient? :)

Appreciate any help from anyone using CloudFlare - thanks!

Comment: If you'd give us the actual domain in question we could check it out for you.

Comment: Actually, it seems to work (I can browse using the CNAME), but it won't show up when using mxtoolbox.com (even though other CNAME's do). The CNAME is okaymaker.invoices.debug.okaymaker.com. Any issue with the main domain name being part of the CNAME subdomain?

Comment: I see `okaymaker.invoices.debug.okaymaker.com` having `A` records pointing at CloudFlare.

Comment: Yup, but it's set up in CloudFlare as a CNAME record. :/

Comment: IIRC, CloudFlare flattens CNAME records so they act as As. https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/